# Async-Await: How to get data in multiple await calls even when there is an error in one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, async-await

So I have this `async` function where I make multiple calls to NodeJS's `DNS Api`. The first two calls return data but because of the third one, the catch block triggers and I don't get the data from the first two.

As it all depends on the type of query(`netflix.com`), some of the await operations might throw an error because of no data. But what I want is I want to get data from the other calls even if there are errors from some of them.

Here's the code:

```
const dnsResolve = async () => {
    const query                 = 'netflix.com';

    try{
        const aRecord           = await dns.resolve4(query);
        const aaaaRecord        = await dns.resolve6(query);
        const cnameRecord       = await dns.resolveCname(query);
     
        console.log(aRecord);
        console.log(aaaaRecord);
        console.log(cnameRecord);
    }catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

dnsResolve();
```

The above code returns

```
Error: queryCname ENODATA netflix.com
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (internal/dns/promises.js:167:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ENODATA',
  syscall: 'queryCname',
  hostname: 'netflix.com'
}
```

Individual outputs from the first two queries:

```
aRecord: [
  { address: '51.73.1.12' },
  { address: '55.83.62.128' },
  { address: '12.12.82.118' }
]
aaaaRecord:  [
  { address: '2406:da200:ff00::222c0:598a' },
  { address: '24206:da00:ff00::22c2:44203' },
  { address: '2406:da0e0:ff00::36de2:41fd' }
]
```

How I want to display the data:

```
[
  { address: '51.73.1.12' },
  { address: '55.83.62.128' },
  { address: '12.12.82.118' },
  { address: '2406:da200:ff00::222c0:598a' },
  { address: '24206:da00:ff00::22c2:44203' },
  { address: '2406:da0e0:ff00::36de2:41fd' },
  { NO CNAME RECORDS }
]
```

Please note that there will be around 6 calls to the `DNS API`. It cannot be determined which one will trigger an error because of no data. It totally depends on the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the very use case [`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) is for:

```
const results = await Promise.allSettled([
    dns.resolve4(query),
    dns.resolve6(query),
    dns.resolveCname(query),
]);
for (const {status, value, reason} of results) {
    if (status === "fulfilled") {
        // Promise was fulfilled, use `value`...
    } else {
        // Promise was rejected, see `reason` for why...
    }
}
```

Or if you only want the successful results:

```
const results = await Promise.allSettled([
    dns.resolve4(query),
    dns.resolve6(query),
    dns.resolveCname(query),
]);
const values = results.filter(({status}) => status === "fulfilled")
                      .map(({value}) => value);
// ...use `values`...
```

Comment: hey man. So I should remove the try-catch block altogether?

Comment: @A.Amit - The promise provided by `allSettled` is guaranteed never to be rejected.

Comment: Sorry for the noob question. So in that sense  I can remove the try-catch block?

Comment: @A.Amit - No worries! You can remove the `try`/`catch` if the only `await` inside it is `await`ing the promise from `allSettled`, yes, since it will never be rejected and `allSettled` handles the rejections of any of the promises you pass into it. If you have *other* promises that might get rejected and you want to handle them, then you'd keep it, but you don't need it if you're passing all of the promises into `allSettled` and using its result.